# strip characters not in allowed selection using javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, replace

I am creating *vanity urls* and I want to only allow the users to have 
`'a-z', 'A-Z', '0-9, '.', ' ', '-', '_'` in their urls.

So given a string I would like to strip all characters that are not in this group.

What is the best way to do this?

Originally I was looping over the string and then checking if the character was in an this string.

But that's obviously not very efficient...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
str = str.replace(/[^\w\s.-]/g,'');
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/6Efc5/1/

This is a regex that matches anything *not* in the `[^]` set globally, and replaces it with an empty string:

- `\w` alpha-numeric and underscore
- `-` dash
- `\s` space
- `.` period

---

**EDIT:** Because I was in the character set, I really didn't need to escape the `.` and `-`. Fixed.

**EDIT2:** As noted by [@Hailwood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/383759/hailwood), the `\s` will match several types of whitespace characters. To allow only a `' '` character, and not others like tab or new line characters, replace `\s` with a simple space.

Comment: is \s just space, or any whitespace character?

Comment: @Hailwood: Ah yes, it'll match several whitespace characters. If you only want a space, then remove `\s` and replace it with a simple space. `/[^\w .-]/`

Answer (score 0):

This will match any characters not in your list: `[^a-z0-9. \-_]`, and then replace them with empty.

```
myString.replace(/[^a-z0-9. \\-_]/gi, "")
```